extracting data from forex factory with selenium
i got the code on the inspect page for what I want, which is the hight impact news and the bank holidays below
Bank Holiday

so how what would be the code for extracting this
I want my python script to print when there is high impact news or bank holidays
it should print high impact news or bank holidays detected.
